# shutil copy adding extra backslashes to paths

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to copy files using

```
from shutil import copy
copy(filePath2, wavDir)
```

filePath2 is string e.g - N:\Tunes Netshare\Memory Stick Archive\Techno wav\Alexander_Kowalski_-_Delicious.wav

but it gives this error
[image]

I've tried a few things such as rebuilding with os.join:

```
tParentFolder = os.path.abspath(filePath2 + "/../../")
fileName2 = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filePath2))[0]
file =  os.path.join(tParentFolder, fileName2 + ".wav")
copy(file, wavDir)
```

Ive also tried pathlib e.g,Path(filePath2), PureWindowsPath(filePath2) etc but all giving the same error

Comment: If you open `cmd.exe` and run `dir "N:\Tunes Netshare\Memory Stick Archive\Alexander_Kowalski_-_Delicious.wav"`, does it work? Does `wavDir` exist? I can't help but notice that what you describe as `filePath2` includes a directory not shown in the error you post (one includes `Techno wav`, the other does not).

Comment: The backslashes are a red herring, that's just the `repr` of a string with the expected number of backslashes as file separators. The actual issue is that the file doesn't exist in the place you're looking.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - well spotted. The os.path.join() method omits a directory in the path, however using filePath2 directly shows the full path in the directory

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `shutil.copy()` is not "adding extra backslashes". An error message like this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\path\\file.ext'
```

Prints the string representation of the path, not the 'actual' string. So, backslashes are escaped, as you would escape them in a string literal, like:

```
my_path = 'C:\\path\\file.ext'
```

The error simply means the file or directory provided does not exist, the problem has nothing to do with the double backslashes you're seeing on the screen. Try `print(file)` and you'll see there's no double backslashes there.

Comment: thanks! It does exist but cannot be accessed for some reason -  which I need to figure out why